# Relation between image of linear transformation and isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $R$ and $S$ are vector spaces over field $F$ and $A\subset S$  is a subspace. All isomorphisms are assumed to be natural. Let $D=\{T\in \mathrm{Hom}_F (R,S)\mid \mathrm{im}(T)\subset A\}$. Show $D$ is a subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}_F (R,S)$. Prove $D\approx \mathrm{Hom}_F (R,A)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_F (R,S)/D\approx \mathrm{Hom}_F (R,S/A)$. How would you prove by constructing isomorphisms with the universal mapping property?

Comment: Hi! Do you have any thoughts? Have you made any progress with any of the part of the problem; where are you stuck? That's a lot of question, so if you can provide more information you'll find it easier to get help.

Answer (score 0):

The projection $S \to S/A$ induces a linear map $\hom(R,S) \to \hom(R,S/A)$. Since $R$ is [projective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_object), this linear map is surjective. Its kernel is obviously $D$. Hence, $D$ is a subspace, and by the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms, we have $\hom(R,S)/D \cong \hom(R,S/A)$.